# Serverless: OperationalError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '.serverless/requirements'

Tags: deployment, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to deploy my changes in serverless. I tried creating a *.serverless/requirements* folder but it gets deleted when I deploy. I also installed *serverless-python-requirements*. Do you know how to fix this or what causes this error?

[image]

This is the command I'm using for deployment:

```
date && sudo rm -rf .requirements.zip && SLS_DEBUG=* serverless deploy --verbose && date
```

Comment: Did you tried to simply run only `serverless deploy` command without `sudo rm -rf` before it? From my experience, `serverless deploy` simply worked fine in that case

Comment: I found the issue, requirements.txt file is missing. After adding that file, everything works perfectly.